# Return Error on "function returning intrinsic value type without return value" with CodeDOM

Tags: vb.net

When compiling VB.NET code, by default the compiler does not give error notification if a function is not returning a value.

You can change this under the project's compiler options to return error on "function returning intrinsic value type without return value".

Just wondering is it possible to achieve the same with the CodeDOM class using VBCodeProvider?

```
Dim provider As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider
Dim params As New CompilerParameters
Dim results As CompilerResults

With params
    .GenerateExecutable = False
    .GenerateInMemory = True
    .IncludeDebugInformation = False
End With

'Compile
results = Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, Source)

Return results
```

Comment: `params.WarningLevel = 4` and `params.TreatWarningsAsErrors =  True` is going to be the most strict CodeDOM has.  I am not sure how that particular one is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify error control via `CompilerParams`:

```
With params
    .GenerateExecutable = False
    .GenerateInMemory = True
    .IncludeDebugInformation = False
    ' add:
    .WarningLevel = 4
    .TreatWarningsAsErrors = True
End With
```

The `WarningLevel` relates to that setting in the C# Compile tab option, but there is not a lot of documentation on it for CodeDOM.  Those would be the most strict settings, so the one you are interested in should be there.